# How can I correctly open my WxFrame loaded from an XML resource file?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm relatively new to both C++ and Wx, so I've been doing a lot of blundering around trying to get this to work over the past few hours, but I seem to have hit a figurative brick wall with this issue.

This code compiles with no errors, but when run, it does nothing. **It simply remains running until terminated (e.g. with Ctrl-C), but a window never opens.**

Here is the C++ source:

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include <wx/xrc/xmlres.h>


class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    wxXmlResource::Get()->InitAllHandlers();
    wxXmlResource::Get()->Load("res.xrc");

    wxFrame MainFrame;
    wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame(&MainFrame, NULL, "MainFrame");
    MainFrame.Show(true);

    return true;
}
```

And here is the accompanying XML file, res.xrc, which should produce just an empty frame containing a sizer within a panel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<resource>
    <object class="wxFrame" name="MainFrame" title="Test">
        <object class="wxPanel" name="TopLevelPanel">        
        
           <object class="wxBoxSizer" name="TopLevelSizer">
                <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
           </object>
        </object>
    </object>
</resource>
```

**Introducing an error into the XML** - for example, adding some spurious characters which are not valid XML - **does cause a window to open,** and it looks like this (under Linux):
[image]

How can I modify my code so that the window will open correctly?

Comment: what wx version? Where is the resource file located relatively to the executable? Can you do `cd wxWidgets/buuildGTK/dsmples/xrc && ls -la` there? (If you build wx yourself). If not - can you install the samples and buiold the xrc sample and run it?

Comment: @Igor Wx 3.1.5, installed via distribution packages. Resource file is in same directory as executable. I'm not sure how to build the samples or even where to get them from. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I presume you are on Ubuntu latest? And work under Eclipse? Can you try to debug and see what is happenning -whether the filwe is actually loaded and then if the frame inside the XDML is actually found?

Comment: Also, I just realized - wxWidgets operates with pointers. Try to use following code: `wxFrame *mainFrame = nullptr; wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame( MainFrame, NULL, "MainFrame" ); MainFrame->Show( true );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainFrame` gets destroyed when you reach the end of the function, which is not at all what you want for a frame which is supposed to exist for a long time. The simplest correct thing to do is

```cpp
wxFrame* MainFrame = wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame(NULL, "MainFrame");
if ( !MainFrame ) {
    wxLogError("Failed to load the main frame from the resources.");
    return false;
}
MainFrame->Show();
```

i.e. just let XRC create a new frame for you (the overload taking the pointer is mostly useful when creating this frame itself, i.e. for passing `this` in it).